# I found a tamarind that was mostly powder, how do I avoid buying these?

Tags: fruit, indian-cuisine

As someone new to tamarind I'm learning new things about the fruit, and discovered something off in one (it was hallow with some black powder inside). Why did this happen, and how can I avoid purchasing a bad one again?

Comment: I suspect that like all fruit you want to select ones that are "heavy for their size", showing that they haven't dried out.  But if you don't have experience to know how heavy it should be, all you have is the others for sale at the time, and they might all be bad.  (I've only purchased paste or compressed into a block, never loose pods, so can't really give specific advice)

Comment: What about buying it in a case like kiwi, and guava are sold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you’re describing mold spores, which I’ve occasionally seen in tamarind. I don’t know of any way to check for this, short of cutting them open to check, but tamarind isn’t particularly expensive so you might just buy a bit more than you expect to need. Often people buy tamarind extract instead, which of course isn’t subject to this problem. (Except for beverages, you really don’t lose anything by using the extract, IMO.)

Comment: I eat tamarind like a fruit similar to how I would eat an apple, or pomegranate